# How to run php file along with maldet

Tags: php, ssh, centos, cpanel

I am running cpanel server with maldetect to keep server clean. When maldetect found malicious file , that account get suspended automatically.

What I want to do is , send email to user and inform him that your account is suspended. Is there any I can do that with with maldetect ?

Comment: what does your research say into that?

Comment: I found only option how to enable option for autosuspend . But havent found any other good resources.